# Server Side Validations not working when .validate() declared inside script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, partial-views

I am using Mvc 4 Application

I have a partialView which inside a Jquery UI dialog, What I am trying to do is add Client side validations on radio button click , But when I add $("#FormID").validate(); into my script what happens is the server side validations do not work . Below is my code

Partial View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_EditDealPartial", "RDeals", FormMethod.Post, new { onSubmit = "return Check_Date();", id = "EditDealForm", @class = "bootstrap-frm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CreateDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CodeGenerated)

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "P", new { id = "PointBased" })
            @Html.Label("PointBased", "Point Based (E.g. Collect xyz Points to earn a FREE meal or $ )")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Point1" style="display: none">
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Collect Points:")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Buy, new { id = "PBuy", style = "width:50px;" })
        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PointEarnType, 1, new { id = "PointEarnType1" })@Html.Label("PointEarnType1", "Earn $(dollars) towards meal:")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Free, new { id = "PFreeDollars", style = "width:50px;" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Point2" style="display: none">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PointEarnType, 2, new { id = "PointEarnType2" })@Html.Label("PointEarnType2", "Earn Free meal:")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Free, ViewBag.FreeList as SelectList, " Select ", new { id = "PFreeMeal" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PointEarnMealText, new { placeholder = "eg:Burger or Fries" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "V", new { id = "ValueBased", @checked = true })
            @Html.Label("ValueBased", "Volume Based (E.g. Buy 5 to Earn 1 FREE meal)")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Volume1">
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Buy)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Buy, ViewBag.BuyList as SelectList, "Select")</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Free)</td>
        <td colspan="2">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Free, ViewBag.FreeList as SelectList, "Select")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Volume2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VolumeBuyText, new { placeholder = "Eg:Burger or Fries" })
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VolumeEarnText, new { placeholder = "Eg:Burger or Fries" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExpiryDate)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpiryDate)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

My Model

```
public class R_DealsMetaData
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Description")]
[Display(Name="Promotion Name:")]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one Option")]
[Display(Name = "Deal Buy:")]
public int Buy { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one Option")]
[Display(Name = "Deal Free:")]
public int Free { get; set; }

public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

public string Type { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Expiry Date")]
[Display(Name = "Promotion Expiry Date:")]
public System.DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

public Nullable<int> PointEarnType { get; set; }

public string PointEarnMealText { get; set; }

public string VolumeBuyText { get; set; }

public string VolumeEarnText { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery Code inside PartialView

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#EditDealForm').validate();

    $("#PBuy").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#PointEarnType").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#PFreeDollars").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#PFreeMeal").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#VolumeBuyText").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter free meal name" } });
    $("#VolumeEarnText").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter free meal name" } });


$("input:radio[name=Type]").change(function () {
    if (this.value == "P") {
        $("#Point1").show();
        $("#Point2").show();
        $("#Volume1").hide();
        $("#Volume2").hide();
        $("#Buy").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#Free").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#PBuy").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#PointEarnType").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#PFreeDollars").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#PFreeMeal").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#PBuy").val("");
        $("#PFreeDollars").val("");
        $("#VolumeBuyText").rules('remove');
        $("#VolumeEarnText").rules('remove');
        $("#PointEarnType1").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please select one option" } });
        $("#PointEarnType2").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please select one option" } });
    }
    else if (this.value == "V") {
        $("#Point1").hide();
        $("#Point2").hide();
        $("#Volume1").show();
        $("#Volume2").show();
        $("#PBuy").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#PointEarnType").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#PFreeDollars").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#PFreeMeal").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#Buy").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#Free").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#VolumeBuyText").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter free meal name" } });
        $("#VolumeEarnText").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter free meal name" } });
        $("#PointEarnType1").rules('remove');
        $("#PointEarnType2").rules('remove');
    }
});

$("input:radio[name=PointEarnType]").change(function () {

if (this.value == "1") {
    $("#PFreeDollars").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#PFreeMeal").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#PointEarnMealText").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#PointEarnMealText").rules('remove');
    $("#PFreeDollars").addClass("input-validation-error");
    $("#PointEarnMealText").removeClass("input-validation-error");
    $("#PFreeMeal").removeClass("input-validation-error");
}
else if (this.value == "2") {
    $("#PFreeDollars").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#PFreeDollars").removeClass("input-validation-error");
    $("#PFreeMeal").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#PointEarnMealText").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#PointEarnMealText").rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter free meal name" } });
    $("#PointEarnMealText").addClass("input-validation-error");
    $("#PFreeMeal").addClass("input-validation-error");
}
});
```

When I check for forms validation

```
var form = $("#EditDealForm");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if (!$(form).valid())
                return false;
            else
                $(this).empty().dialog('close');
```

It return false only for the Client side validation rules which I have added inside the script of partialView but the server side validations returns true the dialog closes. Don't know where i am going wrong

Please Help me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean _the server side validations do not work_? On which properties? Are you referring to rules you have added client side for `VolumeBuyText`, `VolumeEarnText` etc.?

Comment: The data annotations declared inside the model do not work(eg:`Buy`,`Description`,`Free` etc)

Comment: Are your checking `ModelState` for validation errors in the POST method?

Comment: yes i am checking it inside POST method, it returns false

Comment: So if `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` then there are validation errors so it is working. Not sure what your asking or are expecting to happen.

Comment: Actually the problem is that , the form should not get submitted it should return false ,but it just get fired in case to those i have applied .rules() but not in case of applied model dataAnnotations

Comment: Still not clear, but before `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);`, your should add `form.data('validator', null);` so the validator is cleared and then the form can be correctly parsed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64768/discussion-between-kumar-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem by just calling

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form)
```

inside my partial view jQuery script